# What is considered to be the right approach to traverse the LDAP DIT?

Tags: java, ldap, ldap-query

I'm new to the LDAP protocol and servers so please forgive me if I'm asking another trivial question. Let's assume I have the following LDAP DIT with nested groups.

```
dn: dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: top
objectClass: domain
dc: example

# Create a place where users are stored
dn: ou=Users, dc=example, dc=com
ou: Users
description: All strongbox users.
objectclass: organizationalUnit

# Create users
dn: uid=tcruise,ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: person
objectClass: top
uid: tcruise
cn: Tom Cruise
mail: tcruise@example.com
givenName: Tom
surname: Cruise
userPassword: password

dn: uid=sspielberg,ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: person
objectClass: top
uid: sspielberg
cn: Steven Spielberg
mail: sspielberg@example.com
givenName: Steven
surname: Spielberg
userPassword: password

# Create groups
dn: ou=Groups, dc=example, dc=com
ou: Groups
description: Base group organization unit.
objectClass: organizationalUnit

# Employees
dn: ou=Employees, ou=Groups, dc=example, dc=com
ou: Employees
cn: Employees
description: All employees
objectClass: groupOfUniqueNames
uniqueMember: cn=NULL

# Employees (Actors)
dn: ou=Actors, ou=Employees, ou=Groups, dc=example, dc=com
ou: Actors
cn: Actors
description: All actors
objectClass: groupOfUniqueNames
uniqueMember: uid=tcruise,ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com

# Employees (Directors)
dn: ou=Directors, ou=Employees, ou=Groups, dc=example, dc=com
ou: Directors
cn: Directors
description: All directors
objectClass: groupOfUniqueNames
uniqueMember: uid=sspielberg,ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com
```

The users in the example could be assigned to multiple groups and each group has specific authorization level. Therefore I need to get all of the groups the user is assigned to as well as their parent groups (i.e. `tcruise - Actors, Employees`). At this point I couldn't find any examples addressing this issue. What comes to my mind as a solution is:

1. Send a query to the database retrieving all groups the user is assigned to by executing `(&(objectclass=groupOfUniqueNames)(uniqueMember=uid=sspielberg,ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com))`
2. Parse the group `dn` (i.e. split by `,` and remove the first record in the array)
3. Lookup the parents while `parentGroup objectClass == groupOfUniqueNames`

Although this might be working, I don't feel it's right. I was wondering if there is a better way to achieve the same result? Something that's considered to be `best practice` in such situations which would be working in most LDAP server implementations (except AD, as they have a solution to this problem)? Furthermore, could you please provide me a simple example code or links with possible solutions for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If a user is a member of multiple groups it should be expressed directly in each group, by the appearance of his DN in the group's 'uniqueMember' attribute. That goes for the parent groups as well. Don't complicate your life by using the DIT structurally like that to express groups of groups. So all you need is (1) in your list.

Alternatively, Employee should be a group of groups, and its members should be Director, Actor, etc, so when you retrieve a user's direct memberships such as Actor you then start a recursive operation finding the groups of which those groups are members, such as Employee, adding them, rinse and repeat. This can be done in about five lines of code.